# Indexing in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

In the following example, why does the first numpy index gives [1], but the second numpy index gives [ ]? Thanks in advance for the help!

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
print(a[a<2])
>>> [1]
print(a[True, False, False])
>>> []
```

Comment: Read again the docs on numpy indexing? What do you expect this to give? Maybe you meant `a[[True, False, False]]`?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!

Comment: Indexing with a boolean (or tuple of booleans), as opposed to a boolean array (or list) isn't well documented, and should be avoided.  `a[True]` makes (1,3) array, while `a[False]` is a (0,3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the first one, you are selecting index:
`a[a<2]` = `a[[True, False, False]]`
which is different to your second.
`a[True, False, False]`

for your second, you are selecting `True, False, False` index, which doesn't exists in the array. so nothing returns.

Comment: [Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)

Answer (score 0):

here you told the numpy array **a** to select the elements which are **less than 2** and there is **only one** element it is the element **"1"** which has as index 0 in your array.

look at this illustrative example:

```
print(a[a<1])
>>> []
print(a[a<2])
>>> [1]
print(a[a<3])
>>> [1,2]
print(a[a<4])
>>> [1,2,3]
```

try

```
print(a[[True, False, False]])
```

instead of

```
print(a[True, False, False])
```